# EF Migrations, create initial migration from existing db instead of model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a running EF 6.0 application with code first against a SQL Server 2008. At the moment we use the older Database Projects to manage and deploy changes of the schema. The Database has some additional objects, as indexes to boost performance and views and stored procedures which are no used by the application itself but from some legacy components.

I intent to move from Data Projects to EF Migrations. Everything work just fine, as i started with an existing db. But when I use the initial migration to initialize a test db from scratch, all the additional objects are missing of course. Because the initial migration was created from the model and not from the existing database.

Is there a way to create the initial migration from an existing database, instead of the model. Because in my case db and model are already in sync, i just need all objects included, even if they are not used for the model. I do not mind if the indexes, views and sp's are just added as sql command.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx "Use empty database as starting point"